# Cannot run SQL script after the start of a Docker-container with Oracle XE

Tags: oracle, docker

I want to start a Docker-container with Oracle XE and then run an SQL script (ddl.sql) to create some tables in docker-compose.

If I execute all the steps separately, everything works:

```
$ docker run -d --name db --rm -p 49161:1521 -v "C:/data/workspace/vpk/":/home/vpk -e ORACLE_ALLOW_REMOTE=true wnameless/oracle-xe-11g
```

Run a terminal in container:

```
$ docker exec -it db bash
```

Execute the script:

```
root@f3ae34d554af:/# echo exit | sqlplus system/oracle@xe @/home/vpk/ddl.sql
```

However when I tried to run everything via docker-compose (excerpt from YML is below)

```
version: "2"
services:
...
  db:
    image: wnameless/oracle-xe-11g
    container_name: vpk-db
    volumes:
      - ./ddl.sql:/home/vpk/ddl.sql
    command: sqlplus system/oracle@xe @/home/vpk/ddl.sql
    ports:
      - 49161:1521
    environment:
      - ORACLE_ALLOW_REMOTE=true
    networks:
      - default
```

I got the error:

```
ERROR: for 2237511031b6_vpk-db  Cannot start service db: b'OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \\"sqlplus\\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown'

ERROR: for db  Cannot start service db: b'OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \\"sqlplus\\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown'
Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Ok. I found out the full path to sqlplus

```
root@558a4c1f74b9:/# whereis sqlplus
sqlplus: /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/sqlplus
```

and inserted it in docker-compose

```
$ docker-compose.exe up
Removing vpk-db
Recreating 2237511031b6_vpk-db ... done
Attaching to vpk-db
vpk-db | Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus
vpk-db | SP2-0667: Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found
vpk-db | SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory
vpk-db exited with code 1
```

What is going on? Do I log in as a different user when I run `docker-compose` instead of just `docker run ... image` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the next in the docker-compose file:

```
command: ["/bin/bash", "-c", "sqlplus system/oracle@xe @/home/vpk/ddl.sql"]
```

U don't have environment without a shell, so call it directly

Comment: I get

Starting vpk-db ... done
Attaching to vpk-db
vpk-db | /bin/bash: sqlplus: command not found
vpk-db exited with code 127

It looks the command tries to run a local sqlplus, not the sqlplus installed on docker container